# A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in and getting error code AADSTS50058

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory

I am try to integrate a sample Angular application with Azure active directory. For this I  used

- MSAL library of Microsoft.
- My Azure portal subscription is trial for 30 days.

Please find the steps i did.

**Step-1** Register the application in my Trial Azure subscription . Set my redirect URI to http://localhost:4200

**Step-2** Select implicit grant, access token and ID token checked.

**Step-3** App.Module i modified like this.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { MsalModule, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'MyclientId', // This is your client ID
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/MytenantId', // This is your tenant ID
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'// This is your redirect URI
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
      },
    }, {
      popUp: !isIE,
      consentScopes: [
        'user.read',
        'openid',
        'profile',
      ],
      unprotectedResources: [],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
      ],
      extraQueryParameters: {}
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Step 4** My Approute

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { MsalGuard } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [
      MsalGuard
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Step-5** AppComponent

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService, BroadcastService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { CryptoUtils, Logger } from 'msal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  isIframe = false;
  loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private broadcastService: BroadcastService, private authService: MsalService) { }  

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener;

    this.checkAccount();

    this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:loginSuccess', () => {
      this.checkAccount();
    });

    this.authService.handleRedirectCallback((authError, response) => {
      if (authError) {
        console.error('Redirect Error: ', authError.errorMessage);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Redirect Success: ', response.accessToken);
    });

    this.authService.setLogger(new Logger((logLevel, message, piiEnabled) => {
      console.log('MSAL Logging: ', message);
    }, {
      correlationId: CryptoUtils.createNewGuid(),
      piiLoggingEnabled: false
    }));
  }

  checkAccount() {
    this.loggedIn = !!this.authService.getAccount();
  }

  login() {
      const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

      if (isIE) {
        this.authService.loginRedirect({
          extraScopesToConsent: ["user.read", "openid", "profile"]
        });
      } else {
        this.authService.loginPopup({
          extraScopesToConsent: ["user.read", "openid", "profile"]
        });
      }
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}
```

**Step-6** ProfileComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const GRAPH_ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  profile:any;

  constructor(private authService: MsalService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProfile();
  }

  getProfile() {
    this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT).toPromise()
      .then(profile => {
          this.profile = profile;
      });
  }

}
```

I followed the same steps given in following links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular

The application login. When i check the session storage able to see the token. But when visit the **profile component**. It will be throwing the following error. I am unable to understand why i am getting this error. Did i miss anything. Please guide me , what i missed.

```
core.js:6260 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InteractionRequiredAuthError: AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).
Trace ID: 89abda01-6426-4658-8692-7690f74f8d00
Correlation ID: cf52e237-939c-4ce0-875b-d8a5555a0a13
Timestamp: 2020-05-17 20:42:55Z
InteractionRequiredAuthError: AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).
Trace ID: 89abda01-6426-4658-8692-7690f74f8d00
Correlation ID: cf52e237-939c-4ce0-875b-d8a5555a0a13
Timestamp: 2020-05-17 20:42:55Z
    at InteractionRequiredAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (AuthError.js:22)
    at InteractionRequiredAuthError.ServerError [as constructor] (ServerError.js:22)
    at new InteractionRequiredAuthError (InteractionRequiredAuthError.js:24)
    at MsalService.push../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js.UserAgentApplication.saveTokenFromHash (UserAgentApplication.js:1289)
    at MsalService.push../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js.UserAgentApplication.processCallBack (UserAgentApplication.js:845)
    at MsalService.push../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js.UserAgentApplication.handleAuthenticationResponse (UserAgentApplication.js:897)
    at MsalService.<anonymous> (UserAgentApplication.js:667)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41640)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:484)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:469)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you include the fiddler traces?

From the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes):

> This means that a user is not signed in. This is a common error that's
>   expected when a user is unauthenticated and has not yet signed in. If
>   this error is encountered in an SSO context where the user has
>   previously signed in, this means that the SSO session was either not
>   found or invalid. This error may be returned to the application if
>   prompt=none is specified.

I have also seen this happen if there is more than one UPN showing for the user and the expected one is not logging in, so could check for that as well.